# Permanent storage To-Do App Swift

Tags: swift3

I've got a simple to do list app, and I would like the items in the list to appear after the app is closed. What I have so far does not do it, not sure if everything is in the right place?

Code in my first ViewController:

```
var list = [String]()

class FirstViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell   {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
            list.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            myTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        myTableView.reloadData()

        if let x = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "cell") as? [String]! {
            list = x
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Code in my second ViewController:

```
    class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!

        @IBAction func addItemButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
            list.append(input.text!)
            input.text = ""

            UserDefaults.standard.set(input.text, forKey: "cell")
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are `reloading` the tableview at `viewDidAppear` before getting the data. Get your data from user defaults first (set `list`) and then reload the table view.

Hint:-

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        if let x = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "cell") as? [String]! {
            list = x
        myTableView.reloadData()

        }

    }
```